# How to incorporate sound into a Javascript-based website without resorting to Flash programming?

Tags: jquery, interactive, web

Everything about this website affirms my decision to develop interactive websites with javascript and not flash. But one question though, how they do they incoporate sound effect into it? I check the page source and it's not HTML5.

Source: [nissanusa](http://www.nissanusa.com/leaf-electric-car/index#/leaf-electric-car/)

Comment: why down vote the question, atleast add a comment why ?

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvotes either.  It's a good question about how to incorporate sound into a Javascript-based website without resorting to Flash programming.

Comment: actually the sound qns was a side qns, i just want to show ppl how website can be awesome without flash.. might have stepped on some adobe supporters' toes.. one more side qns, how they did managed to incoporate video into the website too?

Comment: the initial animation that you see is probably done using raphealjs, its not a video. but the one you see on "products specs page", is flash.

Comment: I can see how "question" makes sense where the term "qns" is used, but I don't see why. I can see "ques." or "qsn", but why "qns"? I fixed the main post, but it's a shame I can't fix the comments.

Comment: Hi gabe thanks for trying to fix everything i said..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually uses [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/)

SoundManager 2 makes it easy to play sounds using Javascript. By wrapping and extending the Flash sound API, SoundManager 2 brings solid audio functionality to Javascript. [How it works](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/getstarted/#intro)

update, just incase you were wondernig:
the other cool jslibraries the website makes use of include,

1. [Raphaël—JavaScript Library](http://raphaeljs.com/index.html) for vector graphics and animations.
2. [cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/) for fast text replacement with canvas and VML - no Flash or images required

Answer (score 3):

The [Sound Manager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) class still extends over the flash API, It is a good example of using Flash only for handling the backend, the frontend doing the actual work with the sounds.

Albeit you're going on a good path to not develop interactive sites in Flash as you can, It's a hinderance.